# new clause in algorithmic package

Tags: algorithms

I want to define a new clause in algorithmic package (`sync` in my case), so that the code inside that clause would be indented as it was inside a `while` clause for example.

So far I made things work by adding those lines in different places of `algorithmic.sty`

```
\newcommand{\algorithmicsync}{\textbf{sync}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendsync}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicsync}
\newenvironment{ALC@syn}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
\newcommand{\SYNC}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicsync\ ##2\ %
    \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@syn}}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ALC@noend}}{
    \newcommand{\ENDSYNC}{\end{ALC@syn}}
}{
    \newcommand{\ENDSYNC}{\end{ALC@syn}\ALC@it\algorithmicendsync}
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do the job without editing `algorithmic.sty` file?

Comment: You don't need to modify `algorithm.sty` directly. You can include your definitions in the document preamble after loading the required packages, adding `\makeatletter` before and `\makeatother` after it. This is the preferred (best) way to extend existing packages.

Comment: Some of the lines I added are inside `\newenvironment{algorithmic}[1][0]{}` so I can't just put them outside in another file.

Comment: Yes, you can. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Werner says in his comment, it is not advisable to modify the `.sty` files directly. You can include your definitions in the document preamble (after loading the required packages); since your commands use the `@` character, you will need to use `\makeatletter` before the definitions and `\makeatother` after them.

However, I would suggest you to use the [algorithmicx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package instead; this package offers you many possibilities to customize the layout of algorithms and gives you an easy way to define a completely new layout for your specific needs. For example (`algpseudocode` internally loads `algorithmicx`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\algblockdefx{Sync}{EndSync}[1]{\textbf{sync} #1}{\textbf{end sync}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
\Require$n \geq 0$
\Ensure $y = x^n$
\State $y \leftarrow 1$
\While{$N \neq 0$}
\State $X \leftarrow X$
\EndWhile
\Sync{$N$ id odd}
\State $N \leftarrow n$
\EndSync
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: if changing to `algorithmicx` is not an option at the present time, you can still make your definitions in the preamble of your document instead of modifying the `.sty` file directly; simply use `\renewenvironment` to redefine the `algorithmic` environment and include your new definitions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\algorithmicsync}{\textbf{sync}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendsync}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicsync}
\renewenvironment{algorithmic}[1][0]{
\let\@item\ALC@item
  \newcommand{\ALC@lno}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{0}}
{{\footnotesize \arabic{ALC@line}:}}{}%
}
\let\@listii\@listi
\let\@listiii\@listi
\let\@listiv\@listi
\let\@listv\@listi
\let\@listvi\@listi
\let\@listvii\@listi
  \newenvironment{ALC@g}{
    \begin{list}{\ALC@lno}{ \itemsep\z@ \itemindent\z@
    \listparindent\z@ \rightmargin\z@ 
    \topsep\z@ \partopsep\z@ \parskip\z@\parsep\z@
    \leftmargin 1em
    \addtolength{\ALC@tlm}{\leftmargin}
    }
  }
  {\end{list}}
  \newcommand{\ALC@it}{\addtocounter{ALC@line}{1}\addtocounter{ALC@rem}{1}\ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{#1}}{\setcounter{ALC@rem}{0}}{}\item}
  \newcommand{\ALC@com}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{default}}%
{}{\ \algorithmiccomment{##1}}}
  \newcommand{\REQUIRE}{\item[\algorithmicrequire]}
  \newcommand{\ENSURE}{\item[\algorithmicensure]}
  \newcommand{\STATE}{\ALC@it}
  \newcommand{\COMMENT}[1]{\algorithmiccomment{##1}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@if}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@for}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@whl}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@loop}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@rpt}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@syn}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}% new
  \renewcommand{\\}{\@centercr}

  \newcommand{\IF}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicif\ ##2\ \algorithmicthen%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}
  \newcommand{\ELSE}[1][default]{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicelse%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}
  \newcommand{\ELSIF}[2][default]%
{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicelsif\ ##2\ \algorithmicthen%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}
  \newcommand{\FOR}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicfor\ ##2\ \algorithmicdo%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@for}}
  \newcommand{\FORALL}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicforall\ ##2\ %
\algorithmicdo%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@for}}
  \newcommand{\WHILE}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicwhile\ ##2\ %
\algorithmicdo%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@whl}}
  \newcommand{\LOOP}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicloop%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@loop}}
  \newcommand{\REPEAT}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicrepeat%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@rpt}}
  \newcommand{\UNTIL}[1]{\end{ALC@rpt}\ALC@it\algorithmicuntil\ ##1}
\newcommand{\SYNC}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicsync\ ##2\ % new
    \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@syn}} %new
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{ALC@noend}}{
    \newcommand{\ENDIF}{\end{ALC@if}}
    \newcommand{\ENDFOR}{\end{ALC@for}}
    \newcommand{\ENDWHILE}{\end{ALC@whl}}
    \newcommand{\ENDLOOP}{\end{ALC@loop}}
    \newcommand{\ENDSYNC}{\end{ALC@syn}} % new
  }{
    \newcommand{\ENDIF}{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicendif}
    \newcommand{\ENDFOR}{\end{ALC@for}\ALC@it\algorithmicendfor}
    \newcommand{\ENDWHILE}{\end{ALC@whl}\ALC@it\algorithmicendwhile}
    \newcommand{\ENDLOOP}{\end{ALC@loop}\ALC@it\algorithmicendloop}
    \newcommand{\ENDSYNC}{\end{ALC@syn}\ALC@it\algorithmicendsync}% new
  } 
  \renewcommand{\@toodeep}{}
  \begin{list}{\ALC@lno}{\setcounter{ALC@line}{0}\setcounter{ALC@rem}{0}%
    \itemsep\z@ \itemindent\z@ \listparindent\z@%
    \partopsep\z@ \parskip\z@ \parsep\z@%
    \labelsep 0.5em \topsep 0.2em%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}
  {\labelwidth 0.5em }
  {\labelwidth  1.2em }
\leftmargin\labelwidth \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}
    \ALC@tlm\labelsep
  }
}
{\end{list}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
\REQUIRE $n \geq 0$
\ENSURE $y = x^n$
\STATE $y \leftarrow 1$
\WHILE{$N \neq 0$}
\STATE $X \leftarrow X$
\ENDWHILE
\SYNC{$N$ id odd}
\STATE $N \leftarrow n$
\ENDSYNC
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

If you don't want your preamble to look too crowded, you can put the code that goes between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in a new document and save this new document as, for example, `algorithmic-modified.sty` in your current working directory (or in your local TDS tree). Now this file can be loaded in the standard way in the preamble of your document, after having loaded `algorithmic` (you'll have to be careful, since other users working with the document will also have to have access to this new file):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithmic-modified}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
\REQUIRE $n \geq 0$
\ENSURE $y = x^n$
\STATE $y \leftarrow 1$
\WHILE{$N \neq 0$}
\STATE $X \leftarrow X$
\ENDWHILE
\SYNC{$N$ id odd}
\STATE $N \leftarrow n$
\ENDSYNC
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

And here's the contents of `algorithmic-modified.sty`:

```
% redefinition of the algorithmic environment
\newcommand{\algorithmicsync}{\textbf{sync}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendsync}{\textbf{end sync}}
\renewenvironment{algorithmic}[1][0]{
\let\@item\ALC@item
  \newcommand{\ALC@lno}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{0}}
{{\footnotesize \arabic{ALC@line}:}}{}%
}
\let\@listii\@listi
\let\@listiii\@listi
\let\@listiv\@listi
\let\@listv\@listi
\let\@listvi\@listi
\let\@listvii\@listi
  \newenvironment{ALC@g}{
    \begin{list}{\ALC@lno}{ \itemsep\z@ \itemindent\z@
    \listparindent\z@ \rightmargin\z@ 
    \topsep\z@ \partopsep\z@ \parskip\z@\parsep\z@
    \leftmargin 1em
    \addtolength{\ALC@tlm}{\leftmargin}
    }
  }
  {\end{list}}
  \newcommand{\ALC@it}{\addtocounter{ALC@line}{1}\addtocounter{ALC@rem}{1}\ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{#1}}{\setcounter{ALC@rem}{0}}{}\item}
  \newcommand{\ALC@com}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{default}}%
{}{\ \algorithmiccomment{##1}}}
  \newcommand{\REQUIRE}{\item[\algorithmicrequire]}
  \newcommand{\ENSURE}{\item[\algorithmicensure]}
  \newcommand{\STATE}{\ALC@it}
  \newcommand{\COMMENT}[1]{\algorithmiccomment{##1}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@if}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@for}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@whl}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@loop}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@rpt}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@syn}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}% new
  \renewcommand{\\}{\@centercr}

  \newcommand{\IF}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicif\ ##2\ \algorithmicthen%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}
  \newcommand{\ELSE}[1][default]{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicelse%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}
  \newcommand{\ELSIF}[2][default]%
{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicelsif\ ##2\ \algorithmicthen%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}
  \newcommand{\FOR}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicfor\ ##2\ \algorithmicdo%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@for}}
  \newcommand{\FORALL}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicforall\ ##2\ %
\algorithmicdo%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@for}}
  \newcommand{\WHILE}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicwhile\ ##2\ %
\algorithmicdo%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@whl}}
  \newcommand{\LOOP}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicloop%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@loop}}
  \newcommand{\REPEAT}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicrepeat%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@rpt}}
  \newcommand{\UNTIL}[1]{\end{ALC@rpt}\ALC@it\algorithmicuntil\ ##1}
\newcommand{\SYNC}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicsync\ ##2\ % new
    \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@syn}} %new
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{ALC@noend}}{
    \newcommand{\ENDIF}{\end{ALC@if}}
    \newcommand{\ENDFOR}{\end{ALC@for}}
    \newcommand{\ENDWHILE}{\end{ALC@whl}}
    \newcommand{\ENDLOOP}{\end{ALC@loop}}
    \newcommand{\ENDSYNC}{\end{ALC@syn}} % new
  }{
    \newcommand{\ENDIF}{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicendif}
    \newcommand{\ENDFOR}{\end{ALC@for}\ALC@it\algorithmicendfor}
    \newcommand{\ENDWHILE}{\end{ALC@whl}\ALC@it\algorithmicendwhile}
    \newcommand{\ENDLOOP}{\end{ALC@loop}\ALC@it\algorithmicendloop}
    \newcommand{\ENDSYNC}{\end{ALC@syn}\ALC@it\algorithmicendsync}% new
  } 
  \renewcommand{\@toodeep}{}
  \begin{list}{\ALC@lno}{\setcounter{ALC@line}{0}\setcounter{ALC@rem}{0}%
    \itemsep\z@ \itemindent\z@ \listparindent\z@%
    \partopsep\z@ \parskip\z@ \parsep\z@%
    \labelsep 0.5em \topsep 0.2em%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}
  {\labelwidth 0.5em }
  {\labelwidth  1.2em }
\leftmargin\labelwidth \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}
    \ALC@tlm\labelsep
  }
}
{\end{list}}
```

Comment: I'm a co-author of a pretty complicated paper, so switching to another algorithms package is not desired. I'll take this into consideration in future papers :)

Comment: @jutky: I've updated my answer showing you how to proceed with the `algorithmic` package (without changing to a new package).